# Ultrawide Resolution while connected via RDP to a VM of Ubuntu

Tags: virtualbox, display-resolution, xrandr

I'm trying to add 2560x1080 to my list of drop-down resolutions in Ubuntu.

When I am working from home, we RDP into a Windows machine that has a Ubuntu VM running. I think because of this, the monitor's name is "default".

```
$ xrandr
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 4096 x 4096
default connected 1920x1080+0+0 0mm x 0mm
```

Now, xrandr does show 2560x1440 and 2560x1600 but the monitor I use at home is 2560x1080.

This is the cmd I have tried to use with xrandr

```
xrandr --newmode "2560x1080_60.00"  230.00  2560 2720 2992 3424  1080 1083 1093 1120 -hsync +vsync
```

But then I get this error:

```
xrandr --newmode "2560x1080_60.00"  230.00  2560 2720 2992 3424  1080 1083 1093 1120 -hsync +vsync
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
X Error of failed request:  BadName (named color or font does not exist)
Major opcode of failed request:  141 (RANDR)
Minor opcode of failed request:  16 (RRCreateMode)
Serial number of failed request:  19
Current serial number in output stream:  19
```

Not sure if it's because I'm running it as a VM through an RDP connection. This is what *lspci -v* shows me

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: VMware SVGA II Adapter (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: VMware SVGA II Adapter
    Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 10
    I/O ports at d010 [size=16]
    Memory at f0000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64M]
    Memory at f4000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2M]
    [virtual] Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Kernel modules: vmwgfx
```

What am I missing?